# Why is this adding all rows? Insert only when exists?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert a row into mentions when a username exists in the users table.

```
INSERT INTO mentions (user_id)
SELECT USER_ID 
FROM users 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT USER_ID FROM users
    WHERE USERNAME LIKE 'mike'
);
```

However, the above query is adding ALL user_ids into the mentions table -- all 1 million of them.  What am I overlooking here?

Users table schema

```
USER_ID | USER_NAME | USER_STATUS
1       | mike      | active
2       | brian     | active
```

mentions table schema

```
MENTION_ID | COMMENT_ID | USER_ID
```

I have a comment "@mike have you talked to @john lately?" and I'm parsing for the mentions.  If mike is found in the user's table, I want to insert it into the mentions table along with the comment_id.

Comment: If there is a matching user, `WHERE EXISTS` is *TRUE* so all rows are added

Comment: `Exists` only returns whether or not something exists.  If there is a username Mike at all, it will always be true.  Change `Where Exists` to `Where User_Id In` to start.  Your sub-query also needs to tie to the user table.

Comment: You'd also be inserting user ids into `mentions` which already exist there, so this has more issues than the lack of correlation in the subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exists needs to have a correlation to the outer select so something like this

```
INSERT INTO mentions (user_id)
SELECT u.user_id
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS
(   SELECT 1 FROM mentions m
    WHERE u.user_id = m.user_id
      AND m.username = 'mike'
);
```

you can also use IN

```
INSERT INTO mentions (user_id)
SELECT u.user_id
FROM users u
WHERE u.user_id IN
(   SELECT m.user_id FROM mentions m
    WHERE m.username = 'mike'
);
```

#### NOTE:

I removed the `LIKE 'mike'` and just changed it to `= 'mike'`... `LIKE` is used when you need to match partial strings... you can easily do it with `=` if you are looking for the whole string.

if you want to find a partial string then you should include wildcards like so `LIKE "%mike%"`

---

#### EDIT:

with your most recent edit you are trying to do a subquery when you dont need one.

```
INSERT INTO mentions (comment_id, user_id)
VALUES
(your_comment_id,(SELECT u.user_id FROM users uWHERE u.username = 'mike'));
```

However, it seems like you should have some sort of dependency between the tables.. can you post the table schemas?

Comment: Ok, I'm following.  I fixed the query I mentioned.  The subquery should have been FROM users, not FROM mentions.

Comment: Thanks, just added schemas.

Comment: @user2045488 just as i thought... you have the user_id in both tables... you should link to it.. but note you dont want to duplicate rows so you need to check to see if the user is already in the mentions table.

Comment: @user2045488 try running my last query at the end... where you replace your_comment_id with whatever id you need to insert... im assuming the mention_id is auto incremented

Comment: @user2045488 haha thanks :) if you notice I showed you a way to insert more than one column with the select statment :)

Comment: Hmm, so what would I do if I wanted to prevent duplicates in this scenario?

Comment: @user2045488 look up ON DUPLICATE KEY with an INSERT statement

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure USERNAME is in the table mentions?
Maybe you just need:

INSERT INTO mentions (user_id)
SELECT USER_ID 
FROM users 
WHERE USERNAME LIKE 'mike'

Comment: Sorry -- username does not exist in mentions table.  I fixed the query above.